# JavaScript define var shorthand for object of uncertain state

Tags: javascript

What does it mean?

```
var ourObject = ourObject || {};
```

Comment: I don't think it's that line which is breaking your script...What is the issue, where is the error thrown and where is the rest of your code so we can replicate it?

Comment: That was not the source of problem. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much context here, but this idiom is often seen within functions:

```
function name (param) {
    param = param || 'default value';
    // now you can be sure that param has a non-null value
}
```

Comment: So it's just: assing variable to variable or create it?

Comment: I'd say, it's about ensuring that a value is assigned to a variable. The variable `param` is created in the paramater list, but it does not have a value then.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to "What does it mean?", the code above is equivalent to:

```
var ourObject;
if(scope.ourObject) {
    ourObject = scope.ourObject;
}
else {
    ourObject = {};
}
```

Where *scope* above is the current scope of the block of code (by default, `window`).

And it means *if this object (ourObject) does not exist in the current scope, create it and assign it to the local variable ourObject*. It ensures that `ourObject` will never be undefined in the current scope.